# How to PIVOT three columns based on one field in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, pivot

I know PIVOT related questions have been asked in this community before, but I can't seem to find what I need.  I would like to pivot multiple columns based on the same field.  I was able to accomplish the task by writing three separate queries and then joining them, but I was wondering if there is a better way to do it.
Here is the table:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HA1T7.png)
The result I need:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzQED.png)

I cannot embed the images yet, so hopefully the attached pictures will be available.  I need to pivot Location, StartDate and EndDate based on the LocationStatus, so each employee will have a one line record. I can publish my code, but it seems to be very inefficient since I am doing three pivots and a join.
Thank you.

Comment: Please don’t link to images, add all relevant information directly to your question preferably as editable text

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can triplicate the `LocationStatus` column, and then PIVOT on each of them individually:

```
SELECT
    EmployeeID,
    MAX([Primary]) AS PrimaryLocation,
    MAX([Secondary]) AS SecondaryLocation,
    MAX([Primary2]) AS PrimaryLocationStart,
    MAX([Primary3]) AS PrimaryLocationEnd,
    MAX([Secondary2]) AS SecondaryLocationStart,
    MAX([Secondary3]) AS SecondaryLocationEnd
FROM
    (
    SELECT 
        *, 
        LocationStatus+'2' AS LocationStatus2, 
        LocationStatus+'3' AS LocationStatus3 
    FROM 
        TableName
    ) X
PIVOT 
    (
    MAX([Location]) 
    FOR LocationStatus IN ([Primary], [Secondary])
    ) AS A
PIVOT 
    (
    MAX([StartDate]) 
    FOR LocationStatus2 IN ([Primary2], [Secondary2])
    ) AS B
PIVOT 
    (
    MAX([EndDate]) 
    FOR LocationStatus3 IN ([Primary3], [Secondary3])
    ) AS C
GROUP BY
    EmployeeID  
;
```

Comment: Thank you, it's a great and clean solution.